# ADODB Objects and SQL in Excel vba to match codes

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

Currently I am formulating Location codes, with much of the code data ready to be matched. On one sheet I have a state code, county code, and county name (`Area_Name`), and on the other I have the state code and the county name. From here I am trying to copy the county codes onto the other document.

If there is an error in the SQL code, then it would probably be in the portion that changes when it is put into excel. This is because I have already put this code in to SQL server and it works just fine.

```vb
Sub CountyFIPS()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, path As String, file As String, sql As String

    path = "T:\Marketing\Data Analytics\"
    file = "Territory Ranking Worksheet - Final.xlsx"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .connectionstring = "Data Source=" & path & file & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Readonly=false;IMEX=0"";"
        .Open
    End With

    sql = "SELECT b.County_Code_FIPS FROM [Zip Code List for Template$] a INNER JOIN " & _
          "(SELECT * FROM [Sheet6$]) b ON a.State_FIPS_Code = b.State_Code_FIPS AND " & _
          "a.County = b.Area_Name"

    Debug.Print (sql)

    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandling:
    MsgBox ("Source: " & Err.Source & vbNewLine & "Number: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Description: " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & "Help Context: " & Err.HelpContext)
Done:
End Sub
```

VBA kept telling me there was a syntax error in the `from` clause, but now it has transitioned into a "No value given for one or more required parameters" error.

Comment: Check spelling of any column in `SELECT` and `ON` clauses. Also `(SELECT * FROM [Sheet6$]) b` is redundant. Simply use `[Sheet6$] b`

Comment: I did include underscores by accident for State_FIPS_Code, and I replaced it with [State FIPS Code] Like it should have been, so thank you for that. Now I am getting an "automation error"